# How to remove the first row when it is in while loop

Tags: php, file

This is my PHP script,

printing the file.

```
$f = fopen("file_name", "r");

echo "<tbody>";
while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false)
{
        foreach ($line as $cell)
                {
                echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</td>";
        }

        echo "</tr>\n";
}

echo "</tbody>";

fclose($f);

echo "\n</table>";
?>
```

This is the file_name

```
NODE,CGR,TERMID,VMGW,ET
GMSC01,932,1337,,1&-2&-3&-4&-5&-6&-7&-8&-9&-10&-11&-12&-13&-14&-15
GMSC01,932,1338,,1&-2&-3&-4&-5&-6&-7&-8&-9&-10&-11&-12&-13&-14&-15
GMSC01,932,1337,,1&-2&-3&-4&-5&-6&-7&-8&-9&-10&-11&-12&-13&-14&-15
GMSC01,932,1338,,1&-2&-3&-4&-5&-6&-7&-8&-9&-10&-11&-12&-13&-14&-15
```

Now i want to print the file except first row, print the remaining data from 2nd row to till end.

please suggest how to display the file except first row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a counter variable like `$counter = 0;` and increment it on every iteration, than use an `if` condition to skip the first iteration using `if($counter != 1)`

```
$counter = 0;
while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {
    $counter++;
    if($counter != 1) {
        foreach ($line as $cell) {
            echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply read the first line OUT of the while loop :

```
$f = fopen("file_name", "r");
$line = fgetcsv($f);
echo "<tbody>";
while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false)
{
        foreach ($line as $cell)
                {
                echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</td>";
        }

        echo "</tr>\n";
}
echo "</tbody>";
fclose($f);
```

Comment: how can i remove the first row out, if the number of csv files are there, i want to remove first row please share the code

Comment: @John What do you mean by "if the number of csv files are there" ?

Comment: I mean my code fetch from server it will auto updated for every 30min, contain 1000s of lines, so i dont want to fetch first line skip the first line and display the remaining part, in every csv file contains the first line common names and remaining is updated. that is why i want to remove the first line.

Comment: @John Yeah well, that's exactly what the code in my answer do.

Answer (score 0):

```
$f = fopen("file_name", "r");


echo "<tbody>";
$flag=0;
while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false)
{

   if($flag==0)
   {
      //skip the first line
      $flag=1;

   }
   else
  {
     foreach ($line as $cell)
     {
         echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</td>";`
     }

    echo "</tr>\n";
   }

echo "</tbody>";

fclose($f);

echo "\n</table>";

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more efficient version that doesn't stretch the condition over the entirety of the loop contents and uses the `continue` statement to short-cut the first iteration.

```
$first = true;
while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {
    if ($first) {
        $first = false;
        continue;
    }
    echo "<tr>\n";
    foreach ($line as $cell) {
        echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";
    }
}
```